How to handle duplicate key outputs in the Mapper phase for HDFS PageRank implementation?
I was writing the PageRank code to run on HDFS, so I wrote the Mapper and Reducer. The data I have is in the following format: page 'outgoing_links,' such as:
Page_1  Page_18,Page_109,Page_696,Page_579,Page_14,Page_532,Page_705
Page_2  Page_671,Page_231,Page_631,Page_45,Page_79,Page_163,Page_419,Page_653
Page_3  Page_807
Page_4  Page_358,Page_716
....
Page_1000    Page_295,Page_186,Page_585,Page_958,Page_765,Page_495,Page_639

I made the mapper to split the pages into this format: page:[outgoing pages]. What I’m trying to do is assign a rank to a page based on the incoming links to it. For example, if page_1 has two outgoing links, and one of them is to page_18, then page_18 will receive half of the rank from page_1 because it has one of the two outgoing links.
To make it simpler, if we have this dataset:
A    B,C
B    C
C    A,B,D
D    C 

Let’s start with A. If A has outgoing links to B and C, I divide A’s rank equally between B and C. So B gets half of A’s rank, and C gets the other half. I keep doing this for all pages.
For example, I see that A has outgoing links to B and C, which means B and C have incoming links from A. Since A has two outgoing links, its rank is divided by 2 for each B and C.
I implemented this logic in the reducer to sum up all the contributions for each page and complete the formula.
PageRank Formula
The sorting didn’t work correctly at first because the format of the page names was like page_1, and the HDFS terminal sorts keys alphabetically. To fix this, I added zero padding to the page numbers, and it worked fine.
However, I ran into another issue: some pages didn’t have any incoming links. The mapper only printed the initial value for these pages. To handle this, I created two sets in the mapper—one for printed pages and another to check if a page hadn’t been printed yet. If a page wasn’t printed, I made sure to print it.
When I tested the code locally, everything worked well. But in HDFS, I got the wrong output. This happened because HDFS works in a distributed way, and two nodes (it depends) checked the same page, causing it to be printed twice. You can see this in the picture—it’s the output from the HDFS mapper.
HDFS mapper output
I handled this error by creating a counter in the Reducer. If the counter doesn’t equal the current page, I print the page with a value of 0.001. My question is, is there a way to handle this mistake in the Mapper instead of the Reducer?
If you are asking for the mapper and the reducer codes here are they:
Mapper:
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys
import re

initial_rank = 1 / 1000 # 1 / number of pages


def mapper():

    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        page, links = line.split() # Page: [list]
        links = links.split(',') # list[object,object]

        for link in links:
            match = re.search(r'\d{1,4}', link)
            link = match.group(0).zfill(4)

            print(f'page{link}\t{initial_rank / len(links)}') # PR(Pi) / C(Pj)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mapper()

Reducer
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys
import re

d = 0.85
N = 1000

total_contribution = 0
current_page = None

'''There are two parts for the formula'''

# part1
part1 = (1 - d) / N

counter = 1
#part2
for line in sys.stdin: # page   rank_contribution
    line = line.strip()
    page, contribution = line.split()
    contribution = float(contribution)

    # sum the contributions for that page
    if current_page == page:
        total_contribution += contribution
    else:
        if current_page:
            # final rank for the page
            final_rank = part1 + d * total_contribution
            print(f'{counter}\t{current_page}\t{final_rank}')
            counter += 1
        # the next new page
        current_page = page
        total_contribution = contribution

    if counter != int(re.search(r'\d{1,4}', current_page).group()):
        print(f'{counter}\t{current_page}\t{0.001}')
        counter += 1

# print the final page
if current_page:
    final_rank = part1 + d * total_contribution
    print(f'{counter}\t{current_page}\t{final_rank}')

I implemented a Mapper to split pages and calculate rank contributions and a Reducer to sum them up. Locally, everything worked well, but on HDFS, I faced issues with duplicate entries due to distributed processing. I tried adding a counter in the Reducer to handle this, and it worked, but I’m looking for a solution that avoids this issue in the Mapper itself.

You could load data into Neo4j or spark graphframes instead and solve this problem much easier. Why map reduce?
